# query_posts and post thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here is my code:

```
    $data = array('cat' => '3');
    $sliderData = query_posts($data);
```

But I also use custom fields, and post thumbnail, how can I get those?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
       $url = get_post_custom_values("url", $slider->ID);
       $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($slider->ID,"large");
```

Comment: How did you incorporate those variables into your query_posts call?